# How do posts get into the "low quality" queue?

Tags: support

Title says it all: how do posts get into the "low quality posts" queue?

When voting to close a question, there's no "low quality" option, and the "low quality" flag is intended for moderators. Yet, posts end up in the queue. How? More specifically **how do I mark a post as low quality, but not intending moderator attention?**

Answer (score 5):

> When voting to close a question, there's no "low quality" option

There *is*, but only if the question isn't already in the Close Votes review queue. [Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gh0s.png). Its use however is [debatable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195673/295232), since the outcome of a question in the Low Quality Posts review queue is to close it. It's better to use one of the standard close reasons.

> the "low quality" flag is intended for moderators

Well, not really. This is what it says:

> This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

But you're right, in a sense:

> More specifically how do I mark a post as low quality, **but not intending moderator attention?**

Flagging a post as Very Low Quality (or Not An Answer) will put the post in the Low Quality Posts review queue (if it didn't already get a review there) and *simultaneously* puts it into the moderator flag queue. There is really no other option, other than simply downvoting the post to indicate it's a poor quality post.

Comment: Well, now I'm really confused. I only see the "low quality" close option for posts that are in the low quality queue. What prompted the question is that I flagged a post as "low quality", with the intention it would go into the review queue, but it was declined with a note saying "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

Comment: It depends on the site what the moderators do with VLQ flags. On some sites I moderate we leave them alone (except the most obvious ones), on some sites not. I'm curious as well what the policy is here.

Comment: @Aaron I was the one that originally declined the flag, but in thinking about it, I've gone back and converted that answer you flagged to a comment. Sorry about that. Otherwise (and keep in mind I'm the newest one on the team), my experience is that we treat these flags the same as other flags, handling them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: Also note that there are automated low-quality flags that come up due to the content of the post itself. If a post is very short, has a high number of suspicious characters, etc., the post is automatically flagged. I'm sure Glorfindel could give us a bit more specific information.

Comment: @Richard Thanks. That clarifies how the flag is interpreted.